# Get centerPanel controller JASidePanelController

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion, jasidepanels

currently I have 2 controller(A, B, C)

I'm using JASidePanelController. A is my menu controller which will display in JASidePanelController.

How do I track what controller is shown in the centerPanel??
The reason is because in my menulist, I want to change the specific row background according to specific controller..

Comment: Keep those controllers around in AppDelegate and track which is active. Maybe you could subclass your ViewControllers so they'd provide the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `willMoveToParentViewController` as `JASidePanelController` is just a container controller.

So in your view controllers (you may want to subclass UIViewController and just subclass all your view controllers from the subclass that has this in it) you can use this code:

```
# In Your Center View Controllers
def willMoveToParentViewController(parentViewController)
  parentViewController.leftPanel.activeItem = 3 # See note below
end
```

That line that says `See note below` you would then have to get setup to be usable in your left view controller, but that's how you could communicate between the center and left panels.